# Values of a Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, dask

Is there a way to get values of a dask dataframe without using compute function as pandas?

- Pandas: `df.values`
- Dask using compute function: `ddf.compute().values`

Dask using compute function is slow and I have to transform the dask dataframe to json format and to do that I should get the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to transform the dask dataframe to json format and

You may be interested in the `.to_json` method of Dask dataframes

> and to do that I should get the values.

This may not be true

Answer (score 1):

Because Dask is suited for large datasets, performing compute on the full data source does not make sense.

I think you should generate your json file by iterating on partitions.

`df.npartitions` gives you the number of partitions.

You can get a specific partition (for example *n*) with `df.get_partition(n)`.